# Problema obteniendo respuesta ajax, evitando redireccionar a pagina de "action" del form

Tags: php, mysql, json

estoy construyendo un formulario que envia una consulta a mysql, codigo que està en un archivo php. Mediante ajax se espera que devuelva el resultado, de hecho lo hace, pero no logra ingresar al success.

Al ejecutar el formulario redirecciona hacia la pagina reservar2.php y muestra el array del json, que de hecho los valores están correctos; pero en lugar de redireccionar y mostrar el valor, deberia mostrar el alert que tiene configurado.
...................................................................................................

Codigo Formulario:

```
<div class="form-popup" id="myFormLiberar">
  <form action="reservar2.php" method="post" class="form-container" id="myFormLiberar">
    <h1>Cancela tu reserva</h1>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Digitá tu cel" id="liberar" name="liberar" 
    required pattern="[0-9]+" required>

    <input type="submit" class="btn" onclick="liberar()" value="Liberar la reserva :(" id="liberaboton"></>
   
  </form>
</div>

<script>

function liberar() {

       $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myFormLiberar').on('submit',function(){
        

        $.ajax({
            url: 'reservar2.php', 
            type: 'post', 
            dataType: "json", 
            cache: false,
            async: false, 

               var data: = "liberar": $("#liberar").val(),
                  
            success: function(liberar) { 
         


                  if (liberar.status == 'liberado') {
                  
                      event.preventDefault();
                     alert("Tu reserva fue liberada correctamente.");
                      
                      
                  } 
                  
                  if (liberar.status == 'sqlerror'){
                      event.preventDefault();
                      alert("No tienes una reserva o no se pudo liberar.");
                      
                      
                  }
                  

            }
    
    
        });
    });
   });

}


</script>
```

```
reservar2.php:


<?php

include('dbconnection.php');
$dato=$_POST['liberar'];

                if(!empty($_POST['liberar'])){
   $liberar = array();

                             date_default_timezone_set('America/Montevideo');
                             $ahora=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                              mysqli_query ($con, "UPDATE tblhoras SET id_estado='2', id_customer_liberador = '$dato', fechaliberada='$ahora', fechareserva=null, email_customer=null, id_customer=null, nombre_customer=null where id_customer='$dato' and id_estado='1'")  or die("No se actualizo");
     


                                         if (mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){
                                         $liberar['status'] = 'liberado';
                                                                             } else {
                                               $liberar['status'] = 'sqlerror';
                                              }
  
        echo $liberar;
                                 //returns celular as JSON format
                               echo json_encode($liberar);
    
                                            }
?>
```

```
Resultado que muestra:

Array{"status":"sqlerror"}  

o según corresponda:

Array{"status":"liberado"}
```

Donde puede estar el error? gracias

---

Gracias por tu respuesta, lo he puesto asi, y no me ha funcionado:

```
function liberar() {

   $(document).ready(function(){
   
   document.querySelector("#myFormLiberar").onsubmit = (e)=>
   e.preventDefault();
```

...

```
  <form action="reservar2.php" method="post" class="form-container" id="myFormLiberar">
<h1>Cancela tu reserva</h1>

<input type="text" placeholder="Digitá tu cel" id="liberar" name="liberar" 
required pattern="[0-9]+" required>

<input type="submit" class="btn" onclick="liberar()" value="Liberar la reserva :(" id="liberaboton"></>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que no te suceda lo que dices, lo primero que debes hacer es, poner un preventDefault() al input submit, para que no recargue la página y así muestre la alerta.

Un ejemplo:

```
document.querySelector("input.submit").onsubmit = (e)=>{
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Ah!, también haz consultas sql preparadas, porque tu código está muy poco seguro.
Espero haberte ayudado!